# How to check a text editor (file) for the presence of a certain word that the user entered

Tags: python, tkinter

There is a variable email = String Var() that transmits the entered login, I want to check through the open file whether the entered login is already in the text editor Users.txt ,but the compiler writes that it cannot read with the StringVar() data type, the question is that how can I convert the email variable so that open file can read it.. And of course, if there is a string that the user entered in the Entry as login, then a warning is issued that occupied.

```
email = tk.StringVar()

email_entry = ttk.Entry(sign in, textvariable=email)

file = open('C://Users.txt', 'r') data file = file.readlines() for line in datafile: if email.get() in line: return True
```

Compiler error:

```
datafile = file.readlines() io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

I know that swears at the Var type in the line, with a normal tc line, this has never happened, but I don't know how you can get a different input string from the user in the Entry through a regular string, for example.

Comment: Your code has several errors in it. Please [edit] your question and fix them.

Comment: You can't successfully mix tk and gtk. In the code you posted, is `gtk` the gtk package?

Comment: its a misspell, it is ttk. How can i fix this error?

Comment: MattDMo, what errors? Compiler says about 1 error with datafile variable

Comment: @Hashimdev if you copy and past the code you shared into a Python file, it won't run. It has several syntax errors. Please edit your question so that the code is the actual code you're running. The most obvious and likely problem here is that the file can indeed not be read by the script - you probably shouldn't write files in the root of the system drive to begin with, it's possible that the account running the script doesn't have access to files there, or to that particular file. Another option is that whatever wrote the file still has it open and is disallowing you to open it from elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line should be broken up into separate commands, and should be written to ensure the file is closed.

```
with open('C://Users.txt', 'r') as file:
    datafile = file.readlines() 
    for line in datafile:
        if email.get() in line:
            return True
return False
```

Comment: it helped, I changed the directory of the text file, but since the open function accepts only one of the arguments 'w', 'r', 'a',it will be unreadable if I put 'a', and if 'r' then unwritable, and I need it to read first and then write the data to a text editor , how can i do it?

Comment: Read the file to check if the email address is already in it. 
Close the File.
Then if the email address wasn't in the file, reopen it in append mode and add the new email address.

I would use one function for checking if its in the file, and another function for adding it to the file.

   Long term, you might want to consider something more robust than a text file, such as a sqlite3 database

Comment: thanks, i will try this.This is just for practice, I decided to make a small authorization menu

Comment: You have some indentation errors with your with blocks.  You need to close the file from the read action before you can open it with the append action.
When you use a `with` statement to open a file, all of the actions for that file have to happen inside of the `with` block, as that opens a context manager.  When you exit the `with` block, the file will automatically be closed, even if execution exited due to an exception being thrown.
The intention of the True/False return values isn't clear either.
My attempt at your replit:  https://replit.com/@nighanxiety/function-code-v2?v=1#main.py

Comment: Thanks, I have already fixed the problem.
But your code is also suitable